# Retrieving all elements in a list of list

Tags: r

Hi if I have a list of list like so,

```
List of 5
 $ 1:List of 2
  ..$ a: Named num [1:36] 3.29 3.25 3.36 3.26 3.34 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:36] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ b: Named num [1:36] 0.659 0.65 0.672 0.652 0.669 ...
```

say its called `l`, is there a way I can extract all the `'a'` element of the list of list? Currently I can extract a single 'a' element as such, `l[[5]] [['sr']]` but when I try something like 
`l[[1:5]] [['sr']] or l[[1,5]] [['sr']]` it fails.  Help would greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
l <- list(list(a=1:3, b=1:3),
          list(a=3:1, b=3:1))
lapply(l, function(x) x[["a"]])

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 1
```

Comment: Or: `lapply(l,"[[","a")`

Comment: nice +1! Though pretty difficult to understand for beginners.

Comment: Fixed: `Extract <- "[["; lapply(l,Extract,"a")` :-)

Comment: Fix #2:  `lapply(l, getElement, "a")`

Comment: That Fix #2 is actually very sensible as a substitute for `"[["`

Comment: @thelatemail not sure what sort of trick that is, but it works `lapply(l,"[[","a")` mind explaining for the beginners?

Comment: You can call functions like this `"+"(1,2)`. It's the same as `1+2`. That's whats done only with `"[["`, e.g. `l[[1]]` is the same as `"[["(l, 1)`.